# What is the meaning of this sequence of random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let consider a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables $(X_i)_{i\ge 1}$ which takes value in $\{1,...d\}$ with $p_k=\mathbb{P}(X_1=k)$, for $k=1,...,d.$ Let $N \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ which is independent from the $(X_i)_{i\ge 1}$. Then we define for $k=1,...,d$ : $N_k = \sum \limits_{i=1}^{N} \mathbb{1}_{\{X_i=k\}}$.

I have to find the probability distribution of the vector $(N_1,...,N_d)$.

But the fact is that I do not know how to interpret the random variable $N_k$. Indeed the last term of the sum is $\mathbb{1}_{\{X_N = k\}}$ contains the index $N$ which is a random variable.

For instance if we consider $k=1$ then $N_1 =\mathbb{1}_{\{X_1 = 1\}}+...+\mathbb{1}_{\{X_N = 1\}}$.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a concrete example which may help to understand the meaning of $N_k$: you have customers which come to a shop, the $i$th of them spends a certain amount of money $X_i$ between $1$ and $d$. The random variable $N$ may be the number of customers entering in the shop in a certain interval of time, say one hour. Then $N_k$ is the number of customers who have spent exactly $k$ say euros.